# Error when running hp-setup "no device selected"

Tags: usb, printing, printer

I have a new printer HP LaserJet M402dne that I would like to install using the command line.

I run the following command :

```
hp-setup -i
```

I am then asked to choose a connection type, I choose USB and I have the following error message :

> error: No device selected/specified or that suppports this functionnality

My printer is on and connected via USB. Weirdly enough, when I enter :

```
 echo "sometext" >> /dev/usb/lp0
```

the printer prints "sometext"

Can somebody help me install this printer or know why hp-setup won't recognize it ?